# Remove blog-like recent content from <front> page

Tags: 7, nodes

Is there a straightforward way to remove the default content, ie recent posts list, from the front page?

I've read about creating my own page and assigning certain blocks to that page and then setting it as the default starting page.. but I've already got my homepage mostly set up and wondered if it would be easy to do it the other way so I don't have to change all my other settings.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As long as your blocks have been configured to show up on `<front>`, it doesn't matter what your front page is: you can swap it out to whatever you want and it won't affect anything except what appears in the main content area.

So, to swap the default recent posts list with a page of your own (whatever that page may be):

1. Go to *Configuration* → *System* → *Site information* (i.e. head over to `http://example.com/admin/config/system/site-information`)
2. In the *Front  page* fieldset, change *Default front page* from "node" to whatever path you want to use, instead.

To make sure your blocks show up on the front page instead of (or in addition to) specific pages:

1. Click *configure* next to the block you want to modify.
2. Under the *Visibility settings* tab group, select the *Pages* tab, change *Show block on specific pages* to "Only the listed pages" and add `<front>` to the text area on its own line.

Now, now matter what you set the *Default front page* to, the block will show up on the front page.

Comment: does what i need. thanks! Except it's showing the page title now, I"ll have to figure out how to remove that

Answer (score 7):

Another way is to add the following code in your **HOOK_preprocess_page()** function in **template.php**:

```
if (drupal_is_front_page()) {
  if (isset($variables['page']['content']['system_main'])) {
    unset($variables['page']['content']['system_main']);
  }
}
```

This causes the default Drupal frontpage node-list in your theme to disappear. This method won't modify your front page title.

You'll probably want configure *(admin/config/system/site-information)* the **Number of posts on front page** option to lowest possible value (i.e. 1)  to save some performance too.

Answer (score 1):

What content do you want to have on the front page? Why dont you try Panels http://drupal.org/project/panels You can use a panel and make it your homepage. You will also keep your block settings. Also what version of drupal are you using?