# How to display Articles on another page ? not in home page

Tags: taxonomy-terms

I had Crated some articles for my project how to display that all articles on another page ?
not on home page.

Comment: Hello and welcome. Have you tried to look a bit on your own?

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to hide articles page from home page in drupal](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/89787/how-to-hide-articles-page-from-home-page-in-drupal)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Remove blog-like recent content from <front> page](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/18385/remove-blog-like-recent-content-from-front-page)

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for [Views](https://drupal.org/project/views) module:

> You need Views if
>
> - You like the default front page view, but you find you want to sort it differently.
> - You like the default taxonomy/term view, but you find you want to sort it differently; for example, alphabetically.
> - You use /tracker, but you want to restrict it to posts of a certain type.
> - You like the idea of the 'article' module, but it doesn't display articles the way you like.
> - You want a way to display a block with the 5 most recent posts of some particular type.
> - You want to provide 'unread forum posts'.
> - You want a monthly archive similar to the typical Movable Type/Wordpress archives that displays a link to the in the form of "Month, YYYY (X)" where X is the number of posts that month, and displays them in a block. The links lead to a simple list of posts for that month.